# style.visibility javascript is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code

```
                        <tr id="maxHoursId">
                            <td>MaxHours</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="maxHours" size="5" value=""></td>
                            <td colspan="8"></td>
                        </tr>
```

I am calling the following java Script in 
 but the  element is not getting hidden in IE. It works fine in chrome, Firefox

```
function hideMaxHours() {
    var listingType = document.getElementById('listingTypeId').value;
    if (listingType == "FullDay") {
        var trId = document.getElementById('maxHoursId');
        trId.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Comment: How sure are you that the if condition is true? Because setting the style works for me in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/UmL5M/

Comment: You are right, Seems the control is not going in side if condition anyways. So how should the comparison be written? I have checked the java tutorial and according to it, seems like what  i have is right

Comment: What version of IE are you testing in? This works fine in IE9:  http://jsfiddle.net/HH6Wd/

Comment: Can you post some expanded HTML source?

Comment: its a company restricted code, i am sorry i cannot fully paste it

Comment: Please post at least the html for the "listingTypeId" field - without seeing that we can't tell why your if condition isn't working...

Comment: <tr>
        <td>Listing Type</td>
        <td><SELECT  NAME="listingType" id="listingTypeId"
         onChange="showMaxHours()">
          <OPTION SELECTED>FullDay
          <OPTION>Hourly
        </SELECT></td>
        <td colspan="8"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="maxHoursId">
        <td>MaxHours</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="maxHours" size="5" value=""></td>
        <td colspan="8"></td>
       </tr>

Comment: Turned out that there was a space in the value. 'FullDay ', that is what the comparision was not working. Chrome worked but IE did not.

Comment: @AbdusSamad it looks like you found that the problem was unrelated to this question. Should this question be closed?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying trId.style.display = 'hidden'; instead? and when you want it visible again, change it to trId.style.display = 'block';

Comment: Because `display: hidden` wouldn't be valid css.

Answer (score 0):

i tryed

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <table>
<tr id="maxHoursId">
                            <td>MaxHours</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="maxHours" size="5" value=""></td>
                            <td colspan="8"></td>
                        </tr>    
</table>
<script>
    var trId = document.getElementById('maxHoursId');
        trId.style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it works in IE 8, IE6 ,7 maybe doesn't support tr hide,youcan use td

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to hide an element before the document gets the opportunity to load.

To handle this situation, use jquery to execute your function.

For example:

```
    
    
    $(document).ready(function () {       
    function hideMaxHours() {
    document.getElementById('listingTypeId').value;
    if (listingType == "FullDay") {
    var trId = document.getElementById("maxHoursId");
    trId.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else {
    alert("The value of listingType is" + listingType);
    }
    }
    hideMaxHours()
    });
```